# Using JPA, Maven and Tomcat, but getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/Persistence

Tags: java, tomcat, maven, jpa

But looking at other cases I tried to put these dependencies to Maven:

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.21</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I'm trying to run as directly from Eclipse but I keep getting the error:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/Persistence

I don't get it because it should be provided by the javaee-api dependency.

Regards,
Eduardo

UPDATED

Now I tried to use these in my POM:

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.java-persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>jpa-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.Beta-20090815</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.21</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.26</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Once Tomcat wouldn't provide me any of the functionality. But I'm still getting the same error, could it be something related to the dependencies scope? Also, my imports are like:

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
```

How do I tell my container to use the Hibernate implementation?

Comment: As the javaee-api is named it's only an api definition but does not provide an implementation for this one. I assume you need an implementation like Hibernate, EclipseLink etc. And furthermore you defined the scope to "provided" which means it will be provided by an environment like JBoss, Glassfish etc.

Comment: I see, I tried providing an Hibernate implementation but it didn't work. Also, I'm using Tomcat and it should provide an implementation. Does anyone know which would be the necessary dependencies for using JPA and Hibernate?

Comment: How did you so? Can you show the pom for that? Tomcat does not provide JPA implementation, cause it's a servlet engine and not an JEE Server.

Comment: Oh I knew it wasn't a full JEE compliant server but I thought it would have as much as that. I used the POM above. I'm trying to figure out how to provide the hibernate implementation.

Comment: Tomcat is neither a partial JEE server nor a not full JEE it's only and simple a Servlet container (http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/index.html). If you tried with hibernate i can't see in the pom any kind of hibernate dependencies you've posted. Sorry but without that i can't help.

Comment: Updated my POM. I think I'm using the worng imports or not telling the container which implementation to use for JPA. Could you please give me some advice?

Comment: I thinks this will be right direction: http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Tomcat_Web_Tutorial

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally was able to fix the issue. This is the correct POM for Hibernate 4. You should not use hibernate annotations as a dependency starting from 3.5

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.21</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.8</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: I m running into the same problem as you. I get exactly the same error. I copied your pom.xml file but it doesnt work for me. In the following link
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13584269/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-javax-persistence-spi-persistenceprovider 
I have posted some information about my project. Anybody could gimme a hint?