# Class not found: javax.persistence.spi.ProviderUtil

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to set up a simple spring web-application with JPA, but after running `mvn spring-boot:run`, I got the following stacktrace. Of course I tried to search, and found something that the class is not on the "classpath", but don't really know what classpath means in this context and how can I add something to it, and why do I need it. So a bit of help would be awesome.

```
[WARNING]
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:506)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/spi/ProviderUtil
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3075)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:412)
        at javax.persistence.Persistence.findAllProviders(Persistence.java:112)
        at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:79)
        at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:60)
        at hu.creativetribes.sga.configurations.PersistenceManager.<init>(PersistenceManager.java:13)
        at hu.creativetribes.sga.configurations.PersistenceManager.<clinit>(PersistenceManager.java:8)
        at hu.creativetribes.sga.Application.main(Application.java:18)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.spi.ProviderUtil
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 16 more
```

Here is my main method, which is a test for persisting an object:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

        Partner partner = new Partner("test", "test", "test", "test", "test", "test");

        EntityManager em = PersistenceManager.INSTANCE.getEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.persist(partner);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        em.close();
        PersistenceManager.INSTANCE.close();

    }

}
```

The persistence manager enum:

```
public enum PersistenceManager {
    INSTANCE;

    private EntityManagerFactory emFactory;

    private PersistenceManager() {
        emFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("sga-jpa");
    }

    public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return emFactory.createEntityManager();
    }

    public void close() {
        emFactory.close();
    }

}
```

My persistence.xml:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
             version="2.1">
    <persistence-unit name="sga-jpa" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/sg_be" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate" />

            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="5" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="20" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="500" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="50" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="2000" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

and finally my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">


    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>stackoverflow_heplme</groupId>
    <artifactId>sga</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-VIVALDI</version> <!-- Haha, spring. -->

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java-version>1.8</java-version>
        <hibernate.version>4.3.6.Final</hibernate.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine.orm</groupId>
            <artifactId>datanucleus-appengine</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <finalName>sga</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>

                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13584269/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-javax-persistence-spi-persistenceprovider)

Comment: In this context, classpath refers to everything you have in your pom file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you don't need a create entityManager if you want to use hibernate cause it's coming with springboot bundle also persistence provider generating backround below dependency so you don't need persistence.xml too, you can manage both on pom.xml and application.properties.

org.springframework.boot
  spring-boot-starter-data-jpa

add this your pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to include jpa 2.1 dependencies instead of 1.0?